# Exiting rails console with 'n'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I noticed a weird thing. I accidentally typed:

```
@a = n
```

which led to exit of rails console.

On further experimenting I found out even if I just do (in console)

```
n
```

The console exits. If I try any other character, I get error as expected.

```
a
# => NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object
```

I was not able to find any documentaion that stated `n` is used to exit `rails console`. Is this normal? Or my console is breaking cause of some thing that I dont understand at all?

**Versions:**

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-06-29 patchlevel 370) [x86_64-linux]
Rails 3.2.13
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue in debugger. Go through here https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/133 . This is also with pry https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger/issues/55 .

Comment: That makes total sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, works as expected (undefined local ...) for me at least. 
Ruby 1.9.3

Consider reinstalling ruby, maybe? :)

Comment: yeah thats what even I was expecting, Dont know why its acting so weird in my case.

Comment: what is your `gem env`, `rails` version if you installed all properly it should not happen